# jScrollPane conflicts with WooCommerce and dynamic blog pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jscrollpane, woocommerce

I installed the jScrollPane plugin on a WordPress site I am developing. It works great on the site's static pages and I have it styled the way I want it. My trouble is in two places.

The first problem is on the 'shop' page where thanks to FireBug I see that there is some sort of problem with the WooCommerce category drop-down widget I'm using. I confirmed this by removing the widget from the sidebar and the page comes up fine. The client wants that drop-down so I need this fixed. This issue didn't start still I installed jScrollPane.

The second problem is on the 'point of view' page. jScrollPane isn't replacing the standard scroll bar but the div ID is the same. FireBug tells me this is related to the lettering.js script I'm using. Huh? Why only on this page?

This is all I know and as far as I can go. I'm not a programmer so I have no idea what to do next. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Here's the url to the site: http://jeanliu.tempora.com

Comment: If I got to [this page](http://jeanliu.tempora.com/shop/) (which is where I think you want us to go) I get a Javascript error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what lettering is on most other pages:-
http://jeanliu.tempora.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js

This is what it is on your Point of View page:-
http://jeanliu.tempora.com/category/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.lettering-0.6.1.min.js

If you modify the location, it should work.

Comment: Thank you! Your x-ray vision is greatly appreciated. That problem is fixed. Now, on to the woocom problem on the shop page.